# VisualStudioCode me modifica mi texto cuando guardo en react

Tags: reactjs

Supongamos que tengo mi código así:

```
    function HelloWorld(props) {
    return ( 
      <div id = "hello">
        <h3>{props.mytext}</h3> 
      </div>
    );
   }
```

al momento de guardar en el visual studio se me modifica todo y me queda así:

```
    function HelloWorld(props) {
    return ( <
        div id = "hello" >
        <
        h3 > { props.mytext } < /h3> <
        /div>
    );
}
```

mi pregunta es ¿que genera que se me agreguen espacios y enters a mi código?

Comment: Creo haber visto algo similar tiempo atrás y era por una extensión de js o jsx, no recuerdo bien, que me cambiaba el formato al guardar. Podrías revisar que extensiones tienes activadas

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Visual Studio Code tienes? A mí me pasó algo similar con la versión "Insiders" y el plugin Prettier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo más seguro es que tienes extensiones activadas en Visual Code, que al grabar el archivo lo formatean con algún estándar, ej. prettier.

Answer (score 0):

Hola me ocurrio el mismo problema y desinstale el plugins J y resolvi el problema.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]